# how to use negative values in for loops

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

i am trying to get the sum of odd numbers with values starting from -300,000 to 300,000 and i am getting my result as ZERO can anybody help why?

```
var sum=0;
for(var i= -300000;i<=300000;i++){
    if(i%2!==0){
        sum=sum+i
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

what is wrong with my code

Comment: are you sure you understood the problem correctly? the sum of the odd negative numbers equally cancel out the sum of the positive odd numbers.. the answer is zero and your code works fine.

Comment: Well that seems right to me. lets do -4 to 4 ...
`-3 + -1 + 1 + 3`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is absolutely nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: It's very funny. It's just a mathematic issue ^^ Not a code issue

Comment: thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simplified code (with a bit a debug) to understand that there's just a math issue :

```
for (var i= -30;i<=30;i++){
    console.log('i == ' + i);
    if (i%2!==0) {
        sum+=i;
        console.log('sum is now ' + sum);
    }
}
```